# Ruby on Rails: load different partial with radio buttons

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial

I want to load different partials with generated content into a form with ajax.

So how do i make this work?

For example, i have a form with the radio buttons "fruits" and "vegetablles", so when i select one of them, the corresponding partial should be loaded directly into the template dynamically with the right content.

Its a simple form created with scaffolding (edit, show, destroy)
should be prototype normally?

Comment: You need to show what your main page looks like. Then you need to show what each partial looks like. Then you need to tell us what javascript library you plan on using.

Comment: the page is a normal created form generated with scaffolding containing some form fields. the partial should have some collection selects or selects. prototype is normally used in ror3 or am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you do is :

In your controller, you should have the following methods:

```
def fruits
  @myfruit = Fruit.new # what you want!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then, you should have your fruit.js.erb corresponding to that action (suppose you have jQuery here) :

```
$("#fruits-holder").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render @myfruit) %>');
```

You then need a partial view like _fruit.html.erb that contains the html you want

As Codeglot stated, if you want more precise answer, post more information about your problem. I cannot be more specific right now.

Comment: well, normally there is used prototype in ruby on rails 3 or am i wrong?

Comment: so how would it look like with prototype or when using the built in javascript framework (prototype?) of ror?

Comment: rails is moving to jquery in 3.1, and it's easy to instal jquery on older versions, I'd go with that...